# django mysql database connection pool

Tags: mysql, django, connection-pooling

I have multiple mysql databases (physical and logical). Using django 1.3 with multiple database support.

I would like to set up database connection pooling with mysql for django for multiple mysql databases so I can have efficient sharding. What is the way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just been looking at how to do this and came across this implementation. It's a very quick way to spin up your own backend which is really just Django's default mysql backend with some minimal changes.  It does use sqlalchemy to manage the pooling but that additional dependency is a small price to pay.  It's working well for me.

http://menendez.com/blog/mysql-connection-pooling-django-and-sqlalchemy/

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by embedding SQLAlchemy pooling into Django. There are two (more/less ugly)  ways of doing that:

- Patching Django. See [Quick and Dirty Pooling](http://jasonrubenstein.blogspot.com/2008/02/quick-and-dirty-database-pooling-in.html) or [Patch for MySQL and Postgres](http://dumpz.org/67550/)
- [Implement custom database backend](http://node.to/wordpress/2010/02/11/database-connection-pool-solution-for-django-mysql/) (This is a preferred way, because it leaves Django intact).